# Gaussian Process UCB acquisition function: where do the constants come from?

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process, bayesian-optimization

I am trying to understand the GP-UCB acquisition function ([Srinivas et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.3995.pdf)) when applied to compact, convex spaces.

The GP-UCB acquisition function is:

$x_t = \mathrm{argmax}_{x \in D} \quad \mu_{t-1}(x) + \beta_t^{1/2} \sigma_{t-1}(x)$

Where $D \subset [0, r]^d$ for some positive integer $d$, and $r > 0$.

As I understand so far, the parameter $\beta_t$ controls the exploration-exploitation preference of the acquisition function, though I am confused as to how one chooses $\beta_t$:

The authors suggest one assumes a covariance kernel for which the derivatives of sample paths $f$ drawn from the GP satisfy:

$\mathrm{Pr}\{ \mathrm{sup}_{x \in D} |\partial f / \partial x_j| > L\} \leq ae^{-{L/b}^2} \quad j = 1 \dots d$

In which case one obtains $\beta_t$ by:

$\beta_t = 2 \mathrm{log}(t^2 2 \pi ^2 / (3 \delta)) + 2 d \mathrm{log}(t^2 dbr \sqrt{\mathrm{log}(4da / \delta)})$

for $\delta \in (0,1)$.

I understand this means GP-UCB applies (or at least, it's theoretical properties hold) only for "smooth" covariance functions. My lack of misunderstanding most likely comes from my lack of a mathematical background and inability to intuitively understand some of the constants. I can summarise my questions as follows:

1. Am I correct to understand $\delta$ represents the upper limit of the probability that the theoretical regret bounds outlined in the above paper *do not* hold?
2. **More importantly:** For some arbitrary, sufficiently smooth kernel, how does one go about calculating $L$, $a$ and $b$ above?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first point, I understand $\delta$ as you do. With one run of the GP-UCB algorithm, for $\delta = 0.05$, you have a 95 % chance for the regret to be bounded by the bound given in theorem 2.