# tradeoff function for exploration/exploitation in the context of gaussian process bayesian optimisation

Tags: gaussian-process, kernel-trick, bayesian-optimization

First, let's give some context to my issue:

consider an objective function $f(x)$ defined over a compact set $D$, such that there exists $x^*, f(x^*) > f(x) \quad \forall x \in D$. 
My goal is to use Bayesian optimization to find $x^*$, as $f(x)$ is in my application very expensive to compute.

I chose to use as a prior model of the objective a Gaussian process, and I chose as an acquisition function the GP-UCB function as defined in [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.3995.pdf#cite.Ghosal%3A06) :

$$\alpha_t(x) = \mu_t(x) + \beta^{1/2}_t \sigma_t(x)$$

the $t$ parameter indicates the iteration number of the Bayesian optimization process. 
My question concerns the parameter $\beta_t$. For now I define it empirically under the form :

$$\beta_t = \gamma_1^{\gamma_2 t}$$

with $\gamma_1>0, 0>\gamma_2>1$. It allows for exploration in the beginning and more exploitation at each iterations.
I would like to redefine it in a way such that it gives some theoretical guarantees on the result of the optimization.

For example, the article [Gaussian Process Optimization in the Bandit Setting:No Regret and Experimental Design](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.3995.pdf) gives a bound over the regret in Theorem 2 and I would like to understand how to use this theorem.
More precisely, the theorem gives some condition for the theorem to apply over two constants $a$ and $b$ but it does not precise how to obtain those constants for a given kernel, and I would be interested in knowing how to get those constants.

**To summarize, I would like a way to define $\beta_t $ such that I have some theoretical guarantee over some quantities in the Bayesian optimization process (regret, distance to the global maximum or others). As I have also found one, I would also like to know how to find the numerical values for a and b in theorem 2 of the preceding article, for a given kernel. I would accept an answer to any of those two issues I'm having.**

Comment: Wanted to share that I asked basically the same question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/354051/gaussian-process-ucb-acquisition-function-where-do-the-constants-come-from) and do not have a good answer.

I ended up looking for open-source implementations of UCB. The only one I managed to find which doesn't use a semi-arbitrary *constant* is [here](https://github.com/dragonfly/dragonfly/blob/master/dragonfly/opt/gpb_acquisitions.py), which uses $\beta_t = \sqrt{0.2  d  \log(2 d t + 1)}$. I don't understand where this comes from though so it doesn't improve on what you have.

Comment: @dizq22 thank you for the comment, happy to see I'm not the only one in this situation. I'll notice you if I find an answer to this question, and I'm going to try to answer at least partially to yours.

Comment: I'm following this question, too. I will likewise share anything useful!

Comment: @dizq22 Did you try to ask it on math stack exchange ? I know that duplicating questions over multiple stack exchange is not a good practice but given that you did not get answer here for about a year I believe it's legitimate to ask it on another stack exchange.

Comment: I haven't but I'm considering posting. In the end I ended up just using the expected improvement acquisition function instead.